# MGF of squared non-standard normal rv

Tags: normal-distribution, moment-generating-function

For $Z \sim N(1,1/2)$, find the moment generating function of $W=Z^2$.

I tried this:

$$M_W(s)=E[e^{sW}]=E[e^{sZ^2}]=E[e^{s(\mu+\sigma x)^2}]=E[e^{s(\mu^2+2\mu\sigma x + \sigma^2x^2)}]=E[e^{s\mu^2}]E[e^{2\mu\sigma xs}]E[e^{\sigma^2x^2s}]$$

$$M_X(s)=e^{\frac{1}{2}s^2}$$

$$M_{X^2}(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2s}}$$

This gives

$$e^{s\mu^2}{M_X(2{\sigma}{\mu}s)}{M_{X^2}({\sigma}^2x)}=e^{s\mu^2}e^{\frac{1}{2}(2{\sigma}{\mu}s)^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2{\sigma}^2s}}$$

However, when the values of $\mu=1$ and $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{2}$ are substituted in, this does not give the correct answer which is:

$$\frac{e^{\frac{s}{1-s}}}{\sqrt{1-s}}$$

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question only asks for the mistake, I am posting this as an answer.

You made a mistake when you assumed $x$ and $x^2$ are independent.

$$E\left[e^{2\mu \sigma sx} e^{\sigma^2 x^2 s} \right] \ne E\left[e^{2\mu \sigma sx} \right] E \left [e^{\sigma^2 x^2 s} \right]. $$

You will probably need to evaluate the integral here to solve the problem.